# building url encode in Jade template

Tags: javascript, html, pug, urlencode

i have some object which iam rendering to jade

```
obj=
   urls = [urls]
   ids = [ids]
```

i need to generate such url:

```
'http://www.host.com/?urls=["13213", "13123"]&id=["dasd", "dsdad"]'
```

but I am using such template:

```
'http://www.host.com/?urls=#{object.urls}&id=#{object.ids}'
```

which is returning me

```
'http://www.host.com/?urls=13213,13123&id=dasd,dsdad'
```

Comment: Whats the input of `urls` and `ids`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solution is here

```
iframeUrl = "https://host"
      iframeUrl += "&ids=#{encodeURIComponent JSON.stringify parsedData.ids}" unless _.isEmpty(parsedData.ids)
      iframeUrl += "&titles=#{encodeURIComponent JSON.stringify parsedData.titles}" unless _.isEmpty(parsedData.titles)
```